# how to use/activate amazon ami deep learning to use GPUs instead of CPUs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, conda

I recently decided to experiment with amazon aws ce2 - amazon deep-learning ami--3a533040.
However, after connecting to the machine and updating the library, I still cant figure out how to run my on GPUs.

i'm using the GPU compute instance, and i'm activating the source tensorflow_p36.
Yet, when I run the code(configured with Conda) it always run it on the CPUs and not on the GPUs.

Comment: I succeed in the past to run my code on GPUs, so this is why I know its configured with Conda, and even when I downloaded a git project that should work with Conda on gpus, it still choseto run on the cpu when I experiment with the Amazon ami-3a533040

Answer (score 1):

Which instance type are you using to launch the instance? 
Also does your code execute under `gpu` device context?
You can also reach out to AWS Developer forum to get help from community https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=263